# Aframe example webcam, but it shows error

Tags: aframe

i try to A-frame example on my web.
However, on mobile device , there is an error.
this is Alert Message.

`Webcam Error. Not Readable Error. Message:Could not start video source`

i put this example source.
i have no idea, why keep showing this alert message.
i just want to test an example on my phone.
(i found the example on this site.
https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/examples/marker-based/basic.html
)

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<style>
     .arjs-loader {
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
       z-index: 9999;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
     }

     .arjs-loader div {
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 1.25em;
       color: white;
     }
   </style>
<div style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<a-scene embedded arjs>
   <a-marker preset="hiro">
      <a-entity
        position="0 -0.5 0.5"
        rotation="90 0 0"
           scale="0.05 0.05 0.05"
           gltf-model="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/scene.gltf"
           ></a-entity>
       </a-marker>
       <a-entity camera></a-entity>
       </a-scene>
</div>
```

Comment: me too . i use other mobile is normal ,but my mobile show (Webcam Error. Not Readable Error. Message:Could not start video source ),i think that caused by "aframe-ar.js" .